# Converting a PDF into multiple JPGs with iText or other

Tags: java, pdf, jpeg, itext

I have the need to convert any multipage PDF file into a set of JPGs.

Since the PDF files are *supposed* to come from a scanner, we can assume each page just contains a graphic object to extract, but I cannot be 100% sure of that.

So, I need to convert any renderable content from each page into a single JPEG file.

How can I do this with iText?

If I can't do this with iText, what Java library can achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: The term for this is a PDF-renderer.  Is calling a native program an option?  If yes, what platform?

Comment: Not sure. But it must work on Windows (dev) and Linux (test&production)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICEpdf - http://www.icepdf.org/ - has an open source entry version which should do what you need.

I believe the primary difference between the open source version and the pay-for version is that the pay-for has much better font support.

Comment: Seems feasible. At least the home page advertises this feature. Do you know if there is any quick start on JPEG rendering so we can make a raw proof of concept in order to request the official import of the package into the project? (I hate bureocracy but "dura lex sed lex")

Comment: I looked at the project a while back, but we went a different path so I do not have first hand experience with it.  I would suggest registering and download their stuff, to see if any of the demos listed on their web page (which render images) are included.

Answer (score 2):

Ghostscript (available for Windows, Linux, MacOS X, Solaris, AIX,...) can convert...

- ...from input formats: PDF, PostScript, EPS and AI
- ...into output formats: JPEG, TIFF, PNG, PNM, PPM, BMP, (and more).

(The ImageMagick mentioned above doesn't do the conversion on its own -- it uses Ghostscript under the hood, as do many other tools.)

Comment: iText uses Ghostscript and ImageMagick under the hood in the tests. Ghostscript to convert PDF into PNG files, and then ImageMagick to compare the PNG files. Check the `CompareTool ` class in the iText source code for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Sun's PDF-Renderer and JPedal does PDF to image (low and high res.

Answer (score 1):

With Apache PDFBox you could do the following:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdffile);
List<PDPage> pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {
  PDPage page = pages.get(i);
  BufferedImage image = page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 72);
  ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(pdffile.getAbsolutePath() + "_" + i + ".jpg"));
}
```